# copy wp-include/link-template to child theme

Tags: next-post-link, previous-post-link

This is a 3(4) part question.

I want to change some functions in the link template file, but don't want to mess with the core.
Basically I want to make the next/previous buttons to link to the next / previous post of the **current author**, and not just the the next/previous post
(according to this guide https://digwp.com/2012/05/post-navigation-author-category/

**1.** the first question is, Is this even possible?, or I'm I thinking about this the wrong way?

**2.** Can I simply copy the **wp-include/link-template.php** file to my childtheme (and where?)

**3.** Since I just want to change some functions, should I only have those commands in my link-template.php  file in the child theme (instead of the whole one), so the rest can be updated correctly with the wordpress core?

If not, anybody knows anything about this?, this seems to be the only information I can dig upp?

Comment: There might be another way I'm not thinking of, but the `add_action` hooks are built for this kind of situation. Though I don't know if there is one for `previous_post_link` or not. Editing the core of WordPress is *highly* not recommended, you are correct. And copying the `wp-include/link-template.php` file to your child theme is not possible no, your theme is completely different than the files in the `wp-include` folder and is unrelated.

Comment: `add_action('previous_post_link', 'your_new_previous_post_link_function');` is something like how it would look if it exists.

Comment: What function are you using to print the pagination links?

Comment: note that if you do this it will always go to the next post from that author, regardless of wether you came from an author archive or not, if that's ok then there is no issue, but if the place the previous/next links go to depends on where the user came from then you need to mention this as it dramatically changes what needs to be done to get you an answer. Also the answer to the second point is a hard no, that's not how that file or how child themes work, and if it could be done it would mean locking yourself out of security fixes, bug fixes, and feature updates in the future.

Comment: Also did you read the comments? there's a comment from the WP co-founder Mike Little that has a code block with a filter that demonstrates how to do it without modifying core. Given that numerous prominent and important members in the comments weighing in on the article I would take that article with a hefty pinch of salt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked to already has a solution written by the co-founder of WordPress Mike Little:

https://digwp.com/2012/05/post-navigation-author-category/#comment-36899

> In the spirit of constructive criticism, the correct solution to this
> is in two parts:
>
> Firstly, the third parameter to `previous_post_link()` and
> `next_post_link()` is a flag to say keep the same category. Modify your
> theme (probably in `single.php`) to add that third parameter as `true`
> to both functions.
>
> Next, add the following **5** lines of code to your theme’s `functions.php`.
> **That’s it: five lines is all that’s required to do the job properly.**
>
> ```php
> function keep_same_author_get_next_post_where($where, $in_same_cat,
> $excluded_categories) {
>   global $post;
>   return $where .= " AND
> p.post_author='" . $post->post_author . "'";
> }
> add_filter('get_next_post_where',
> 'keep_same_author_get_next_post_where', 10, 3);
> add_filter('get_previous_post_where',
> 'keep_same_author_get_next_post_where', 10, 3);
> ```

This solution looks well written and straight forward.

There is a lot of information out there on WordPress and a lot of bad practices being recommended. I've left out some of Mikes more colourful comments on the subject but they're readable if you click through.

---

To directly answer your bullet points for completeness:

> 1. the first question is, Is this even possible?, or I'm I thinking about this the wrong way?

Yes! See previous text in answer for the solution

> 2. Can I simply copy the wp-include/link-template.php file to my childtheme (and where?)

No, child themes allow you to override theme templates loaded using the theme templating system. They can't be used to replace arbitrary files such as JS files or core WP files just by dropping a file with the same name in the child theme and hoping it gets used instead.

I would note that in this situation, the name of the file `link-template.php` is unfortunate and implies things it should not.

> 3. Since I just want to change some functions, should I only have those commands in my link-template.php file in the child theme (instead of the whole one), so the rest can be updated correctly with the wordpress core?

If you ever need to change the behaviour of WordPress core, you should use filters and actions in a plugin or theme. This is also the case for modifying the behaviour of 3rd party plugins. Note that sometimes a filter or action wasn't added by the authors but there are ways to get around that, and it's a question that has already been asked on this stack with some very good and detailed answers by myself and others, so I recommend searching for those.

Comment: Thnx for the answer, My theme didn't have any single.php, (not those lines) could you add the code to the single.php file to?

Comment: you could, but these are hooks/filters so they don't normally go inside theme templates, they go inside plugins or your themes `functions.php`

Comment: Like Mike said: ***"add the following 5 lines of code to your theme’s functions.php"***

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I misunderstood, since you wrote **edit the single.php and add a third parameter** and I didn't find it, but adding just the 5 lines you suggested seems to be working, Thnx A lot!

Comment: oooh, in that case you just need to find the calls to those 2 functions, if you don't have a `single.php` then it will be in another file

Comment: Well, they got to be somewhere, because I just copied your code, addedd to the functions.php and it works, without  editing single.php

Comment: yeah, look up the template hierarchy, `single.php` is just one level in a stack of fallback templates that ends at `index.php`, you might have a `post.php` or `singular.php` etc etc